# Autocomplete in make based on possible targets

Tags: bash, make, autocomplete

The `Makefile` is:

```
%.pdf: %.tex
    rubber -d $<
```

If there is a `doc.tex` in the directory, then `make doc.pdf` builds `doc.pdf`. The problem is that when I type `make`, the autocompletion gives nothing: it doesn't even allow to autocomplete to `make doc.tex`. What can be done about it?

Comment: Completion is handled by `bash-completion`, not by `bash`, nor by `make`. `bash-completion` needs a list of valid targets to show you. I don't think it's possible to convince `make` to produce such a list when you're using wildcard rules.

Comment: Even zsh's completion isn't that smart.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/516305/21348

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188324/bash-completion-of-makefile-target

Answer (score 5):

The `bash-completion` package doesn't do this, it does some acrobatics to handle both command line options and extract a list of `Makefile` targets, but it does not try to generate matches by applying wildcards or otherwise handling any *pattern rules*.

It can be done however, here's a simple version with a few caveats.

```
function _mkcache() {
    local _file="$1"
    # add "-r" to omit defaults (60+ rules)
    ${MAKE:-make} ${_file:+-f "$_file"} -qp 2>/dev/null |
    gawk '/^# *Make data base/,/^# *Finished Make data base/{
      if (/^# Not a target/) { getline; next }
      ## handle "target: ..."
      if (match($0,/^([^.#% ][^:%=]+) *:($|[^=])(.*)/,bits)) {
          #if (bits[3]=="") next # OPT: skip phony
          printf("%s\n",bits[1])
      }
      ## handle "%.x [...]: %.y [| x]", split into distinct targets/prereqs
      else if (match($0,/^([^:]*%[^:]*) *(::?) *(.*%.*) *(\| *(.*))?/,bits)) {
          #if (bits[3]=="%") next # OPT: skip wildcard ones
          nb1=split(bits[1],bb1)
          nb3=split(bits[3],bb3)
          for (nn=1; nn<=nb1; nn++) 
            for (mm=1; mm<=nb3; mm++) 
              printf("%s : %s\n",bb1[nn],bb3[mm])
      }
      ## handle fixed (no %) deps
      else if (match($0,/^([^:]*%[^:]*) *(::?) *([^%]*)$/,bits)) {
          if (bits[3]=="") next # phony
          printf("%s : %s\n",bits[1],bits[3])
      }
      ## handle old form ".c.o:"  rewrite to new form "%.o: %.c"
      else if (match($0,/^\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+): *(.*)/,bits)) {
          printf("%%.%s : %%.%s\n", bits[2],bits[1])
      }
    }' > ".${_file:-Makefile}.targets"
}

function _bc_make() {
    local ctok=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}   # curr token
    local ptok=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]} # prev token
    local -a mkrule maybe
    local try rr lhs rhs rdir pat makefile=Makefile

    ## check we're not doing any make options 
    [[ ${ctok:0:1} != "-" && ! $ptok =~ ^-[fCIjloW] ]] && {
        COMPREPLY=()
        [[ "$makefile" -nt .${makefile}.targets ]] && 
            _mkcache "$makefile"

        mapfile -t mkrule < ".${makefile}.targets"
        # mkrule+=( "%.o : %.c" )  # stuff in extra rules

        for rr in "${mkrule[@]}"; do
            IFS=": " read lhs rhs <<< $rr

            ## special "archive(member):"
            [[ "$lhs" =~ ^(.*)?\((.+)\) ]] && {
                continue # not handled
            }

            ## handle simple targets
            [[ "$rhs" == "" ]] && {
                COMPREPLY+=( $(compgen -W "$lhs" -- "$ctok" ) )
                continue
            }

            ## rules with a path, like "% : RCS/%,v" 
            rdir=""
            [[ "$rhs" == */* ]] && rdir="${rhs/%\/*/}/" 
            rhs=${rhs/#*\//}

            ## expand (glob) that matches RHS 
            ## if current token already ends in a "." strip it
            ## match by replacing "%" stem with "*"

            [[ $ctok == *. ]] && try="${rdir}${rhs/\%./$ctok*}" \
                              || try="${rdir}${rhs/\%/$ctok*}"

            maybe=( $(compgen -G "$try") )  # try must be quoted

            ## maybe[] is an array of filenames from expanded prereq globs
            (( ${#maybe[*]} )) && {

               [[ "$rhs" =~ % ]] && {
                   ## promote rhs glob to a regex: % -> (.*)
                   rhs="${rhs/./\\.}"
                   pat="${rdir}${rhs/\%/(.*)}"

                   ## use regex to extract stem from RHS, sub "%" on LHS
                   for nn in "${maybe[@]}"; do 
                       [[ $nn =~ $pat ]] && {
                           COMPREPLY+=( "${lhs/\%/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}}" )
                       }
                   done
               } || {
                   # fixed prereqs (no % on RHS)
                   COMPREPLY+=( "${lhs/\%/$ctok}" )   
               }
            }
        done
        return
    }
    COMPREPLY=() #default
}
complete -F _bc_make ${MAKE:-make}
```

There are two parts, a function `_mkcache` extracts all the rules and targets from a `Makefile` and caches these. It also does a bit of processing so the rules are simplified to a single "`target : pre-req`" form in that cache.

Then, a completion function `_bc_make` takes the token you attempt completion on and tries to match against targets, and uses the pattern rules to expand a glob based on the pre-requisites and the word for completion. If one or more matches are found, it builds a list of targets based on the pattern rules.

GNU `make` is assumed. It should correctly handle:

- targets and pattern rules (though not all of them, see below)
- new and old form `.c.o` → `%.o : %.c`
- paths in prereqs (e.g `RCS/`)
- with or without all default rules (add `-r` to `make` if preferred)

Caveats, and not supported:

- intermediate or chained dependencies, it's not as smart as `make`
- `VPATH` or `vpath`
- `.SUFFIXES`
- `make -C dir`
- "archive(member)" targets, explicit or implicit
- `make` options expansion
- pathological junk in the environment that can cause Makefile parsing problems (`TERMCAP` for example)
- Makefiles named other than `Makefile`

Some of the above can be added relatively simply, others like archive handling are not so simple.

Comment: "a simple version" 

Comment: Perhaps simple in terms of features, rather than implementation 